# Using the FUEL SDK for PHP, how can I access portfolio items

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to be able to get an array of all the images I have in a specific portfolio folder but there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to do this on the site. Is this something that has been implemented in the FUEL SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like it's implemented directly in the SDK, but you can use the methods layer to access everything as shown in the over view video.

Here is the object reference - http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/portfolio/

Be sure to watch this video here - https://code.exacttarget.com/sdks - it goes into detail about using methods directly.